# How much negative space needed? To recognizably remove a space by letting something be added? For macros whose argument is another macro?

Tags: spacing, macros, tex-core, xparse, parsing

Suppose that one has `brea +` (notice the space at the end).

`brea +` is *not* printed yet. A macro `\m{brea +}` will replace `+` with `\added` ... how then does one define `added`, imagine it prints a `d` but only so that

`bread` results strictly instead of `brea d`?

`\newlength{\test}\settowidth{\test}{~}` and then `\hspace*{-\test}` works inside the .pdf as far as removing the space is concerned. Copying and pasting does not interpret as any space; but if the result `brea \added` is passed into something like the answer to [Extract more than nine arguments that occur periodically in a sentence to use in macros in order to typset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480991/extract-more-than-nine-arguments-that-occur-periodically-in-a-sentence-to-use-in), where each space is used as a separator for logic, will it still be recognized?

> So if the pdf sees no space character, generally safe to assume LaTeX sees no space, and thus no separator where ~ is parsed as a separator for words? I am correct then in assuming LaTeX sees only bread as the output, because with the negative spacing "added", the threshold for the conditional for a space to be recognized is not flipped? (How it exactly does LaTeX "think" about space inside macros when the argument is the expansion of other macros.)

QUESTION: In other words, *how much negative space needed to make sure LaTeX or xparse does not detect any space as being present?*

> Example: Using code [Extract more than nine arguments that occur periodically in a sentence to use in macros in order to typset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480991/extract-more-than-nine-arguments-that-occur-periodically-in-a-sentence-to-use-in/480995#480995) ... and let `\NewDocumentCommand{\form}{m}{\lowercase{#1}}` ...

For `\fun{ABBB BCCC CDDD DEEE}` we expect `ABBB BCCC cddd DEEE` and get it.

For `\fun{ABBB BCCC \hspace{-\test}CDDD DEEE}` we expect  `ABBB BCCCCDDD deee` and get `ABBB BCCCcddd DEEE` ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking, but if this is about LaTeX parsing the space (as opposed to the output in the PDF: `\unskip`?) then I don't think there is any amount of 'negative space' you can add to get rid of the space. What can be done depends on your exact use case, I guess. Here it might make sense to have `\m` simply replace `<space>+` with `\added` and not just `+`.

Comment: @moewe `\hspace*{-\test}` certainly works visually and as far as the pdf is concerned.
But does it ultimately remove the space, or simply shifts to the right? I think \kern removes the space as if was never there, but may be wrong about that. Basically, what is the length of `~` that is recognized as ~, if there is any such length? At the lowest level? It is a length > x <=> "space", or a strict token that cannot ever be removed?

If no way to totally remove in the output that any `~` was there to begin with, that is also a valid answer. It would be something important to be aware of.

Comment: @moewe Basically would \somethingelse{\m{brea +}} = `\somethingelse{bread}` or that still `\somethingelse{brea d}`? After `\m` performed negative spacing equivalent to exactly one `~`, between `a` and `d`?

Comment: @moewe pdf does have a notion of space characters, it is tex who has not (but one can insert one e.g. with `\pdfinterwordspaceon` or with tagpdf + interwordspaceon. )

Comment: @UlrikeFischer @moewe So if the pdf sees no space character, generally safe to assume LaTeX sees no space, and thus no separator where `~` is parsed as a separator for words? I am correct then in assuming LaTeX sees only `bread` as the output, because with the negative spacing "added", the threshold for the conditional for a space to be recognized is not flipped? (Been using LaTeX for a long time and just recognized don't know about how it exactly "thinks" about space inside macros when the argument is the expansion of other macros.)

Comment: @GuidoJorg sorry I don't understand a word. It would be much easier to get what you want, if you would should concrete code.

Comment: TeX sees spaces when they are in the input: I suspect you are talking about PDF viewers and how they 'include' spaces in copy-pasted output. That is beyond TeX's control and depends on which viewer we are talking about.

Comment: There is absolutely a difference between `fish`, `f \unskip ish` and `f \hspace*{-\test}ish`. Just because there is no visible space in the PDF that does not mean that there is no space for TeX in the input. I don't think it makes sense to talk about TeX seeing a space in the output. *We* see something in the output, *TeX* only sees the input and works through it step by step (more or less; and only the last step if you will is the output).

Comment: @GuidoJorg there is no length specified in tex that answers your question. Different PDF viewers will have different heuristics for guessing when to ignore a small space as being an inter-letter kern rather than a word space, it is not under TeX's control.

Comment: AFAICS the `\fun` you mention just splits the input at space *characters* in its argument when it is called. If you want it to ignore a particular space you need to remove that space before you call the function with that argument. Check out what output you get from `\fun{ABBB BCCC \hspace{-\test}CDDD DEEE}`: `ABBB BCCCcddd DEEE`. There is no visible space in the PDF output, yet TeX has clearly seen it when it executed `\fun`.

Comment: Now check out `\newcommand*{\testtext}{ABBB BCCC CDDD DEEE EFFF}` and `\fun{\testtext}` and compare that with `\expandafter\fun\expandafter{\testtext}`.

Comment: This and the previous question feel like we are in an 'XY' situation. You are asking to do some things that seem very vague or arbitrary. Probably a question on what you actually want to do would be good, with real data and a real sense of what you need out.

Comment: @Joseph-Write Trying to break up the large automation use case into much simple examples where the principle is clear so that I can learn to write such solutions in general. What typically breaks is the composition. Individual macros work fine. But don't compose and troubleshooting where there are low level things I don't know that I should know ... If they remain unknown, probably would _not_ be able to to write a slightly different solution to a similar but not quite the same automation problem ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, you could do several things, for example:

1. given `{brea }` and `d` remove the space  *token* and so produce `bread`.
2. Typeset `brea` remove the skip glue generated by the space token, and then typeset `d`.
3. Typeset `brea` skip by the negative of a word space, then typeset `d`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\z{brea }
\def\zz{d}

\def\AAA#1 {#1}

\begin{document}


1. \expandafter\AAA\z\zz

2. \z  \unskip \zz

3.  \z \hskip -\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font \zz



\end{document}
```

Note that only (1) here is equivalent to typing `bread`, with the other variants any font-specified ligatures or kerns between `e` and `d` would be lost.

In the generated PDF neither (1) nor (2) will have a space specified (unless (1) has an inter-letter kern and (2) does not) but (3) may or may not have a space specified depending on the ability of the PDF generator to optimize away the two spaces totalling zero width.

---

Showing Ligatures and kerns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\AAA#1 {#1}

\begin{document}

\def\z{brea }
\def\zz{d}

1. \expandafter\AAA\z\zz

2. \z  \unskip \zz

3.  \z \hskip -\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font \zz

\def\z{V }
\def\zz{o}

1. \expandafter\AAA\z\zz

2. \z  \unskip \zz

3.  \z \hskip -\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font \zz

\def\z{snif }
\def\zz{f}

1. \expandafter\AAA\z\zz

2. \z  \unskip \zz

3.  \z \hskip -\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font \zz



\end{document}
```

Comment: That clarifies things, will be accepting this answer. It may be that impossible to delete the space in that order of composition, one macro inside the other, where the first can only replace + in `brea +` with `d` or some other code like `\unskip d` and that is what goes into another macro that requires `bread` and not `brea d`. So for example `\fun{ABBB BCCC\unskip CDDD DEEE}` works but `\fun{ABBB BCCC \unskip CDDD DEEE}` does not and `\fun{Abbb Bccc {\hskip -\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font} Cddd Deee}` in place of `\unskip` won't work.

Comment: @GuidoJorg you have still not said what you mean by "space" here, of the things I suggested, only `\AAA` removes a space token. `\unskip` does not act on tokens at all, and removes a glue node (so only does anything _after_ text has been typeset) and the third one of course doesn't remove anything at all it just adds an additional glue node.

Comment: I mean by "space" something that _does not_ trigger as ~ when xparse looks for it. We start with `salad toast eggs brea + oats milk` and a macro `\m` transforms + into `?` and trying to understand what, if anything "?", makes this into `salad toast eggs bread oats milk` instead of `salad toast eggs brea d oats milk` which however in pdf _appears_ "as if" `salad toast eggs bread oats milk`.

Trying to eliminate fragility. Cannot touch the space between "a" in "brea" and "+", only replace + with something. And if I understand correctly, not possible at all, even if nothing is typeset yet.

Comment: @GuidoJorg you are making it very hard to understand, In normal document code `~` does not parse as a space it is an active character adding linebreak penalties as well as a space.  If you are looking at parsing space tokens then only the first version i give above is relevant at all, neither `\unskip` nor  `\hskip` work at the level of tokens.